# bones not moving objects

Tags: modeling, animation

i'm pretty new to blender, and i'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV6XP-EDzw8. finished the tutorial before with no problems but when i decided to make my own object, now the bones set up in the appending and rigging section of the video won't move the model at all. I'm pretty sure its something simple i'm missing, but it would be really helpful if someone could tell me whats wrong.

heres the model with all the bones in their starting positions:
[image]

and now heres the model with all the bones moved to the right:
[image]

as you can see, nothing changes.

thanks!

Comment: Well if yoru object is not moving than weight painting must be missing. Go to weight paint, select bone and check if there is weight paint for the bone... How did you weight paint it? Did you use automatic weight paint?

Comment: I didn't know weight painting was a thing, so it would be automatic or not in the model at all, ill check it out, thanks

Comment: The whole model was blue, which I assume is the automatic weight painting. Should I paint the whole thing?

Comment: Try to choose with ctrl+P Armature Deform with Automatic weights... If your model is blue it means you have no weight painting, blue color means that it wont be affected by bone at all, red means it will get affected with full strenght, It is good to learn more about weight painting before you will start with this, try some tutorials or try those automatic weights and then you can try to adjust it by yourself (remember to use small strenght, something like 0.2 for placed that should move less)

Comment: Oooh I see, that tutorial totally jumped over weight painting, he used pre-made arms with weight painting already applied and didn't show you how to do it

Comment: I cant select a bone to paint, is it because the bones are in a different object?

Comment: Bones for weight painting are selected through vertex groups,

Comment: well the individual vertex groups are all weight painted to full red from what i can see (when i select the vertex group for the mag, it turns red), and the main vertex group (weapon) has the whole model weight painted red. Is that how its meant to be?

Comment: hmm yes it can be like that but it may be not right... is there way that you can share file with us? It will be much easier and faster for me or someone else to look at it and find your problem

Comment: sure, https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amx-KcbDnbA6dxQnjlsL2prsKso?e=FPVU57

Comment: i made another model and tried to do the same thing, and got the same problem. I really don't know what to do